# reCaptcha always returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, recaptcha

Possibly a duplicate question. I have a SPA and implementing reCaptcha which I am running in localhost and gives me an error: "false\nincorrect-captcha-sol". The code I am using is shown below as from the original source [here](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/07/28/adding-recaptcha-to-your-single-page-applications/). It was working before with the same keys(private and public). What could I possibly change or check to make it work?Thanks

```
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var PK = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["recaptchaKey"];//private key
        var userIP = ((HttpContextBase)this.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
        var uri = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("privatekey", PK));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("remoteip", userIP));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("challenge", data.Challenge));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response", data.Response));

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        string responseFromServer = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
                .ContinueWith((readTask) => readTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        if (responseFromServer.StartsWith("true"))
        {
            return Contact(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the docs your are posting to the wrong URL
Its siteverify instead of Just verify in the end.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: I changed to the mentioned url before but only got as far as this error:"{\n  \"success\": false,\n  \"error-codes\": [\n    \"invalid-input-response\",\n    \"missing-input-secret\"\n  ]\n}"

Comment: You're not passing the right fields on POST
The proper fields are:

secrete
response
remoteip (this one is optional)

Please take a look at the doc I sent you.